# How to load labeled data to train CNN model?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I am trying to load my dataset to train cnn model :
my dataset is like :

```
- Dataset
- Train
    - Person
        - person_image1.jpg
        - person_image1.xml
        - person_image2.jpg
        - person_image2.xml
        ...
    - Dog
        - dog_image1.jpg
        - dog_image1.xml
        - dog_image2.jpg
        ...
- Valid
    - Person
        - person_image1.jpg
        - person_image1.xml
        - person_image2.jpg
        - person_image2.xml
        ...
    - Dog
        - dog_image1.jpg
        - dog_image1.xml
        - dog_image2.jpg
        ...
- Test
    - Person
        - person_image1.jpg
        - person_image1.xml
        - person_image2.jpg
        - person_image2.xml
        ...
    - Dog
        - dog_image1.jpg
        - dog_image1.xml
        - dog_image2.jpg
        ...
```

I labeled the images with labelImg and choosed the pascalVoc as save format .
this is an examle of label : person_image1.xml

```
<annotation>
    <folder>Person</folder>
    <filename>428.jpg</filename>
    <path>/home/cnn/dataset/train/Person/428.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Person</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>55</xmin>
            <ymin>86</ymin>
            <xmax>112</xmax>
            <ymax>158</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Person</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>122</xmin>
            <ymin>94</ymin>
            <xmax>169</xmax>
            <ymax>166</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I used this code :

```
    class_mapping = {'Passenger': 0, 'Phone Violation': 1, 'Seat Belt': 2, 'With Helmet': 3, 'Without Helmet': 4}

# Function to load and preprocess images and labels
def load_data(folder_path):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for class_name in class_mapping:
        class_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, class_name)
        for image_file in os.listdir(class_folder):
            if image_file.endswith('.jpg') or image_file.endswith('.png') or image_file.endswith('.jpeg'):
                image_path = os.path.join(class_folder, image_file)
                label_file = image_file.split('.')[0] + '.xml'
                label_path = os.path.join(class_folder, label_file)
                print("image_path",image_path)
                print("label_path",label_path)
                if os.path.isfile(label_path):
                    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
                    img = cv2.resize(img, (416, 416))  # Resize images to a consistent size
                    img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values between 0 and 1
                    images.append(img)

                    # Parse the XML file to extract label information
                    tree = ET.parse(label_path)
                    root = tree.getroot()
                    # Extract the necessary label information from the XML
                    # XML follows Pascal VOC format:
                    xmin = int(root.find('object/bndbox/xmin').text)
                    ymin = int(root.find('object/bndbox/ymin').text)
                    xmax = int(root.find('object/bndbox/xmax').text)
                    ymax = int(root.find('object/bndbox/ymax').text)

                    print("class_name",class_name)
                    label = class_mapping[class_name]
                    print("label",label)
                    print('xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax',xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
                    labels.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, label))

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)

# Load train images and labels
train_images, train_labels = load_data(train_folder)

# Load valid images and labels
valid_images, valid_labels = load_data(valid_folder)

# Load test images and labels
test_images, test_labels = load_data(test_folder)

# Combine train images and labels
train_data = (train_images, train_labels)

# Combine valid images and labels
valid_data = (valid_images, valid_labels)

# Combine test images and labels
test_data = (test_images, test_labels)
```

But I get bad trained model :

- Train Loss: 1030294208.0000
- Train Accuracy: 0.0000e+00
- Validation Loss: 1030294208.0
- Validation Accuracy: 0.0

THANKS